# Current source with Op-amp and FET

Tags: power-electronics

What is the maximum load resistance that can be connected to a current source? How can I count it?
[image]

All elements are basic from microcap. Op-amp basic generic with level1

Comment: The circuit as shown does not look particularly useful.

Comment: Why is everything grounded?

Comment: Is V5 actually 150V? Also, this question is very similar to another, which has not yet been clarified or answered. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668990/op-amp-constant-current-source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Op-Amp Constant Current Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/668990/op-amp-constant-current-source)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it's my homework, it's not for particularly useful, the circuit is from some book, and the requirement to do it work correctly

Comment: @Hearth because i'm not good at electronics, so i suppose that grounding in the top can be deleted?

Comment: @PStechPaul yes that was my question but the circuit didn't woks so i did the new one  that is working as i suppose but there are some issues may be.. only i have to do is theoretical scheme

Comment: @Andyaka that was my unanswered question and it was stupid cause the scheme didn't work

Comment: It can't work without properly connected power supplies and hopefully your book shows something rather different. You should also indicate which resistor you intend  to be the load.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany unfortunately i don't know how to redo it... cause i don't quiet understand how could it work

Comment: What you have drawn cannot work. So maybe you should edit your question to also include the image from your book  (don't forget to give attribution).

Answer (score 2):

A constant current source works by adjusting it's output voltage to source a fixed current through a variable load resistance. The maximum load resistance that a current source can drive is the voltage the source can output divided by the current. The voltage it needs to be able to output is the current times the resistance. This is basic [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).

For example, if you have a 1 mA current source and you want to use it to get 1 mA through 10k\$\Omega\$ it would need to output \$ 1 mA \times 10k\Omega = 10 V\$. If the load was changed to 5k\$\Omega\$ the current source would adjust it's output voltage to \$ 1 mA \times 5k\Omega = 5 V\$. How high of a resistance it can source the set current through would depend on how much voltage it can drive the load with, which will generally be the supply voltage minus the minimum voltage drop across the active element and sense resistor.